# Forced to switch from iframe to SDK for share buttons

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I was using an iframe share button solution to be able to share products or posts on facebook. I used this systeme wich worked great on about 10 different websites but this week, they all ended up no working.

I read I should get an appId for each website and use Asynchroneous SDK, which I did, and followed steps to get it to work:

1. Load the SDK with appId authentification.
2. Load jQuery if needed (some buttons require it).
3. Add button code were desired.

I can see the SDK is loaded in `<div id="fb-root"></div>` but the share button never appears on the page and it is not a layout issue. I have tried several different buttons but they all seam to never make it to the user.

I read a lot of posts about the issue but each one was magically solved on Jully 22nd... not mine. I need help implementing this first button as I need to fix many websites afterwards. Thx!

Comment: did you force FB to crawl the pages?

Comment: no I did not, what is the use of it and if it should be done how do I do it?

Comment: ... since no one else chimed in, I'll go out on the limb here, see below.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a fresh implementation of FB btns I ended up going here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

to force FB to crowl the pages I was working on at the moment.
This proved usedful in getting immediate feedback on how things were working out.

Comment: Thank for the debugger page, it'll come usefull in the future but for now:
I had bugs concerning my og tags, fixed them easily and now the debugger tells me there is no error and no warnings but still no button. I can find it in the element inspector but it is greyed out like visibility:hidden elements.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest at this point is posting relevant source snippets with your question. Any luck finding clues to it on FB dev resources?